# Why does my vector not rotate correctly OpenGL/GLM?

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, glm-math

I am trying to learn how to do some transformations on 3d points in OpenGL. Using [this cheat sheet](http://antongerdelan.net/teaching/3dprog1/maths_cheat_sheet.pdf) I believe that I have the correct matrix to multiply to my vector which I want to rotate. However, when I multiply and print the new coord, I believe that it is incorrect. (Rotating 1,0,0 90deg cc should result in 0,1,0 correct?) Why is this not working?

**My code:**

```
glm::vec4 vec(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); 
glm::mat4 trans = {
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, cos(glm::radians(90.0f)), -sin(glm::radians(90.0f)), 0.0f,
    0.0f, sin(glm::radians(90.0f)), cos(glm::radians(90.0f)), 0,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f 
};
vec = trans * vec; //I should get 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 right?
std::cout << vec.x << ", " << vec.y << ", " << vec.z << std::endl;
```

The above prints `1.0, 0.0, 0.0` indicating that there was no change at all?

I also tried using the `rotate` function  in GLM to generate my matrix rather then manually specifying but I still did not get what I think should be correct (I got a different wrong answer).

```
glm::mat4 trans = glm::rotate(trans, 90.0f, glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0));  //EDIT: my bad, should've been z axis not x, still not working
```

The above prints: `-2.14..e+08, -2.14..e+08, -2.14..e+08`

(PS: I just took Geometry in the previous school year, my apologies if the math is incorrect. I have a basic understanding of matrices and matrix multiplication that I picked up today to learn OpenGL transformations but other then that I'm sort of a noob at this)

Comment: If the Input is (1,0,0,1) and the Output should be (0,1,0,1), you rotation should be around the Z Axis.

Comment: @HannesHauptmann ok, I tried making that change, but it still doesn't return the correct answer `glm::mat4 trans = glm::rotate(trans, 90.0f, glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0));`

Comment: On the left side you see how OpenGL handles it. I am 100% this is a rotation around the Z axis :)

Comment: @HannesHauptmann you are right I'm sure. I just am getting mixed up probably. But I tried the Z axis and it still isn't working?

Comment: I am currently checking the glm specifications, I never used GLM before ^^

Comment: @HannesHauptmann thanks. I'm just using it because 3 different tutorials have recomended it. However, I'm not fixed on it, if you know of a better library for the transformations let me know!

Comment: glm is a good library, I just wanted to implement the stuff by myself, learned a lot with doing so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, you're rotating a unit vector on the x-axis
around the x-axis and that doesn't change the vector (imagine
rotating a pencil around itself, the direction doesn't change at all).

To achieve what you previously wanted, you should rotate the
vector around the z-axis using the matrix like this:

```
glm::mat4 trans = {
    cos(glm::radians(90.0f)), -sin(glm::radians(90.0f)), 0.0f, 0.0f,
    sin(glm::radians(90.0f)), cos(glm::radians(90.0f)), 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
};
```

Besides that, `glm::mat4 trans = glm::rotate(trans, 90.0f, glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0));` isn't returning the desired result because trans need to be initialized before passing it to glm::rotate. Try writing it like this:

```
glm::mat4 trans; // Default constructor called, trans is an identity matrix
trans = glm::rotate(trans, glm::radians(90.0f), glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0));
```

Still, you might not get the expected vector (0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f) due to precision loss when using glm::radians and cos/sen. In my test, I got the vector (-4.37113883e-008f, 1.0f, 0.0f) and -4.37113883e-008 is really -0.0000000437113883 which is a number very close to 0, the expected result.

Comment: Ah thank you Jean. This is also what @HannesHauptmann was telling me.

Comment: I think the reason I was confused on the rotate() command is because I'm used to java. I didn't realize mat4 was an obj (because it doesn't start w/ capital) and also I never realized it was initalized with a constructor (because in java you would use new and then call constructor explicitly). See, this is why C++ confuses me lol

Answer (score 2):

The reason why your own rotation matrix is not changing the input is simple: your rotation only affects y and z coordinates and since those are zero the result is exactly the same as the input. X coordinate has a multiplier of 1 into the output x coordinate so that stays the same.

You can make the vector `1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0` for example and then you will see changes.

As for the glm version, can't say why it would give strange result, I have never had issues with them but haven't used much.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer Sami. +1 because this helped. I'm accepting Jean's though since it has more info (explains why the `rotate()` ) command doesn't work. I hope you don't mind.